# Unable to get JPA Entity manager working with java config (XML free)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, aspectj, compile-time-weaving

I'm able to configure the datasource, JPA transaction manager and Spring aspects jar file. To be precise I want AspectJ compile time weaving (CWT). Please share any clues to get this done if someone has done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled into this problem recently and got this figured by including this tag in the spring XML: `<context:spring-configured/>` which is one of the requirement for CWT.
If you are using XML free java configuration then here is the annotation for the same effect: `@EnableSpringConfigured`. Hope this would work if other configurations are in place!